# Locking portions of code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have been asked to build an HTML template in Visual Studio Code that contains "blocks of code that are not editable".

The template is for users who are beginners with HTML and will be required to go in and make minor content updates to a webpage. There is concern that these users may inadvertently break the HTML or introduce errors.

I don't see any way to do this via the default features of Visual Studio Code.

This is an example. The content in the `<head>` and `<h1>` tags should be "not editable".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weekly update</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your weekly update</h1>
    <p>Check back weekly for the latest news from the College.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would expect that this would require you to develop a custom extension for VSCode.  Of course it's worth noting that these same users can circumvent your custom extension by disabling it, removing it, or simply not using VSCode to edit the file.  Overall this sounds like overkill for what is essentially a non-issue.  Users certainly can break code on their own computers, and observing the results of that is a great way to learn.  But it does no harm to anybody else.

Comment: If this actually is a template, why not use it as such, and have a template engine in your build process?

Comment: define the locked blocks/portion of the template in a parent template and use a template engine